# What’s the difference between React event and DOM event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I’ve tried searching for an answer to this, but couldn’t find solution on the internet.

This looks pretty interesting question. Can anyone please explain if there is a real difference.

Comment: Any example where we can see different behavior in different browsers? and react works same way in all browsers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A React event is also known as a [`SyntheticEvent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html).

From [`React#SyntheticEvent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html):

> **a cross-browser wrapper around the browser’s native event. It has the same interface as the browser’s native event, including stopPropagation() and preventDefault(), except the events work identically across all browsers**

`SyntheticEvent` contains `nativeEvent`, which can be used to access browser-specific events and event-handling mechanisms.

**DOM event :**

nothing but a `nativeEvent` mapped to the browser in which the app is running.

e.g.

1. **onchange** (*React having onChange*)
2. **onclick** (*React having onClick*) etc.

**EDIT :**

e.g.  using `onclick`
< IE9

```
element.attachEvent('onclick', function() { /* do stuff here*/ });
```

other browsers (including IE 9 and above):

```
element.addEventListener('click', function() { /* do stuff here*/ }, false);
```

As we can see, we need a script to handle cross-browser compatibility. One very popular library, **[jQuery](https://jquery.com/)**, has done so many such things to overcome cross-browser compatibility issues.

If you check even the jQuery docs or JavaScript ([e.g. official docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick)) for the compatibility of different APIs for different browsers, you will easily get what exactly is meant by **events work identically across all browsers**.

I have taken the above snippets from [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick).

Comment: Any example where we can see different behavior in different browsers? and react works same way in all browsers?

Comment: @G_S please see EDIT

Comment: Thanks a lot Riyaj. Mostly compatibility issues are for the old browsers.Its not for the latest browsers (atleast IE >=10)

Comment: Thanks Riyaj for your detailed explanation.

Answer (score 6):

React gives you a `SyntheticEvent`, a `cross-browser wrapper` around the `browser’s native event`. It has the same interface as the browser’s native event, including `stopPropagation()` and `preventDefault()`, except the events work identically across all browsers.

The `native event on DOM element` can be accessed through `nativeEvent attribute` from the synthetic event.

Synthetic event contains the following attributes

```
boolean bubbles
boolean cancelable
DOMEventTarget currentTarget
boolean defaultPrevented
number eventPhase
boolean isTrusted
DOMEvent nativeEvent
void preventDefault()
boolean isDefaultPrevented()
void stopPropagation()
boolean isPropagationStopped()
DOMEventTarget target
number timeStamp
string type
```

Check the [`React documentation on Events`](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html)

Consider the example,

```
DOMEvent      ReactEvent(Synthetic event)
onclick       onClick
onchange      onChange
```

Comment: Any example where we can see different behavior in different browsers? and react works same way in all browsers?

Comment: Thanks Subham for your detailed explanation.